# how to merge vectors with different sizes using R

Tags: r, vector, merge

I am trying to put together 3 vectors of different sizes in R but i keep getting error message

First i created a dummy vector

```
dummy <- mat.or.vec(10,3)
dummy[,1] <- myVec1
dummy[,2] <- myVec2
dummy[,3] <- myVec3
```

Since all myVec1, myVec2 and MyVec3 has different sizes i get the following error message

```
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: Why try to force them into a matrix if they don't have the same length? If the goal is to have them into one same data structure (i.e. object), then use a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont really understand *why* you are combining three columns of different lengths. But maybe this will get you the results you're after

```
dummy <- mat.or.vec(10,3)
dummy[1:length(myVec1), 1] <- myVec1
dummy[1:length(myVec2), 2] <- myVec2
dummy[1:length(myVec3), 3] <- myVec3
```